# iPhone: How to display a full screen view by code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a Tab Bar, with 2 tabs. When I click the first tab, it have a View showing "View 1", and I want add a button on "View 1", that can take me to a new full screen view "Full Screen View 1". also, in the "Full Screen View 1", it have a button to return to "view1", and exit full screen.

So, my question is how to implement these two buttons. (The button in "View 1", and the button in "Full Screen View 1") (If can't implement full screen, at least full enough to cover the tab bar.)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you may want to take a look at the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property on [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You'll need to have a [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in the tab in order to use it. If you don't want to see the navigation bar you can use `-setToolbarHidden:animated:` to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest way to do it is to present a modal view controller. This way you don't have to mess with the tab bar at all:

```
[myTabBarController presentModalViewController:view1Controller animated:YES];
```

To exit the full screen view simply use:

```
[myTabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```